# Windows hg authorisation failed

Tags: windows, mercurial, authorization, credentials, http-status-code-401

I have an hg repository in Windows, but the following comands :

```
hg pull
hg push
hg incoming
hg outgoing
```

all have the result :

```
abort: authorization failed
```

When I try to access my repository by a web browser, it asks for my credentials. I input them and I can access them without problems from the web browser.

In my mercurial.ini file, I've added

```
[auth]
bb.username = MyUserName
bb.password = MyPwd
```

and I've checked that the environment variable HGRCPATH is correct, but it didn't solve anything.

The output of **hg incoming --debug --traceback** is :

```
using http://My/Repo/url.com
sending capabilities command
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyc", line 97, in _runcatch
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyc", line 778, in _dispatch
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyc", line 549, in runcommand
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyc", line 869, in _runcommand
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyc", line 840, in checkargs
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyc", line 775, in <lambda>
File "mercurial\util.pyc", line 512, in check
File "mercurial\extensions.pyc", line 143, in wrap
File "mercurial\util.pyc", line 512, in check
File "hgext\mq.pyc", line 3528, in mqcommand
File "mercurial\util.pyc", line 512, in check
File "mercurial\commands.pyc", line 3854, in incoming
File "mercurial\hg.pyc", line 548, in incoming
File "mercurial\hg.pyc", line 500, in _incoming
File "mercurial\hg.pyc", line 122, in peer
File "mercurial\hg.pyc", line 102, in _peerorrepo
File "mercurial\httppeer.pyc", line 264, in instance
File "mercurial\httppeer.pyc", line 57, in _fetchcaps
File "mercurial\httppeer.pyc", line 197, in _call
File "hgext\largefiles\proto.pyc", line 174, in httprepocallstream
File "mercurial\httppeer.pyc", line 121, in _callstream
Abort: authorization failed
abort: authorization failed
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's all you have in the `[auth]` section of the mercurial.ini you're missing the required `.prefix` entry.  It's required to know what sites to use that username and password on.  See http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#auth for details on how to use the `prefix`.

Also make sure you see a http/s URL when you do `hg paths`.  If you're seeing the ssh URLs then you need to set up a key not a password (or switch to the http/s URLs).